# linux server hosting .py files that are reading .txt files but cant store in variable

Tags: python, linux, file

I have a linux server. 
It is reading files in a directory and doing things with the full text of the file.

I've got some code. it retrieves the file path.

And then I'm doing this:

```
for file in files:
        with open(file,'r') as f:
            raw_data = f.read()
```

Its reading the file just fine. And Ive used this exact code outside of the server and it worked as expected. 
In this case, when run on the server, the above code is spitting out all the text to the terminal. But then raw_data == None.

Not the behavior I'm used to. I imagine its something very simple as I am new to linux in general.

But I'm wanting the text in the file to be stored in the 'raw_data' variable as a string.

is there a special way I am to do this on linux? Googling so far as not helped much and I feel this is likely a VERY simple problem.

Comment: Can you paste the output from the server?

Comment: What you're doing is very standard, and should work. Make sure you process the data in `raw_data` before you read the next file though.  But ultimately, more context is needed to really help.

Comment: i cannot. as its confidential info. But it spits out exactly whats in the file. 
I figured it out tho. User error. I over complicated it because im unfamiliar with linux and thought maybe it was behaving differently in that enviroment. But no.. It was something else I did. A buried print in a sub process that uses the the data in the file was spitting it to screen. And as for the None type being returned.... well.. like i said... user error. thanks for checking tho.

Answer (score 0):

User error.

I thought, due to my noob status in linux, that perhaps the enviroment was causing weird behavior. But buried deep in the functions that use the data from the files was a print statement i had used a while back for testing. That was causing the output to screen.

As for the None type being returned. It was being returned by another subfunction that had a try/except block in it and was failing. The variable being referenced had the same name (raw_data). So i thought it came from the file read. But it was actually from elsewhere.

thanks all who stopped by. User error for this one.